# Why is there no connection with my external database (Spring/JpaRepository)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have external database from which I want to query data via requestmapping in Spring. I have configured my application.properties file like this:

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
# Connection url for the database "testdb"
# (I made up the hosting address for security reasons) 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://23.119.144.321:3306/testdb

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**PROBLEM:** When I try to request the list of users from the requestmapping i UserController I just get an empty list. Also I tried fetching one User from the database via gettingUser method in controller but Spring just returns a blank white page instead of data in json format. I don't know where the problem occurs. I have 3 records in my User table in db (so the db is not empty).

**SOLUTION:** SEE THE CHECKED ANSWER.

Comment: you should have some exeption in console log ?

Comment: Nope no errors and no exceptions just INFO messages about ASTQueryTranslatorFactory and the DispatcherServlet.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right schema? because it could be possible Spring is connecting to another schema and creating tables from scratch due to the ddl configuration you have.

Comment: How can I check whether I am connecting to the right schema or not?

Comment: First, make sure your logs show the connection string you defined on your properties, then log into database either by command line or mysql workbench using same connection details. List and explore all databases created on that instance and browse listing all tables available. You should find tables for your entitites only on testdb.

Comment: Can you give me a walkthrough link of how to do all of that? I am new to Spring :). Thanks for your response btw.

Comment: Because you enable sql-logging: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` you can see actual sql executed by hibernate. Paste it here or try to understand why they returns empty result. 
p.s. you can add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` for pretty format sql logs

Comment: **This is what I get from the console= Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, user0_.email as email2_1_, user0_.name as name3_1_, user0_.pass as pass4_1_, from user user0_**

Comment: **I think I found the issue**: the query that is generated is using the name of the table without caps. So it select from the table "user" instead of "User" which is the one that I have in my db. That is why it is handled as a new table which therefore kept being created everytime I drop the "user" table.  So is there a way to tell jpa or spring that it should use the table "User" with caps instead of "user" ?

Comment: @MoNigma Just because you see 'user' does not mean Spring is confused with table name. If you include the whole query, you will see that is not the case.

Comment: Where is your `UserDaoService` code?

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I deleted it by accident. Now I included it again. So how can I change the query for it to access my User table with a capital U instead of "user"? Because it is making a connection with the db but everytime it creates a new table called "user" instead of using my existing "User" table.

Comment: Table names in most databases, including MySQL, are not case-sensitive so the difference between "user" and "User" most likely is not the cause of your problem. And in any case, if you would have tried to query from a table that doesn't exist in the DB, you would have gotten an error telling you that the requested table does not exist.

Comment: Nope there is no such error because I have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update which means that If it doesn't find that table then it creates it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: Firstly, What does this do? Secondly, I found out that Spring IS making connection with the db but it sees my User class as user without the capitalized U. But in my db I have the one I need with a capital U. So do you know a way to make spring of jpa accept my User class as User (capital U) and not as "user"?

Comment: yeah so that line makes sure JPA uses the exact names for the entities that you specify when its generating the queries. Adding that line should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

User is [reserved keyword in mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Probably this causes error can you try to change your entity table name. Then save a new user with your application and fetch resulting data with endpoint.